# Jenkinsfile update using version control

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I've a Jenkinsfile in the `master` branch of the repository with following code

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('A') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Step A"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a new stage B for which I created a git branch `update/jenkinsfile` and in that branch the Jenkinsfile is now

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('A') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Step A"'
            }
        }
        stage('B') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Step B"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make Jenkins to use Jenkinsfile from branch B not from master in order to testing the change?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a [`when`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) statement.

As I understand it, you want to execute stage B **when** you are on branch `update/jenkinsfile`. In order to do this, you need to add a condition to stage B:

```java
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('A') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Step A"'
            }
        }
        stage('B') {
            when {
              branch 'update/jenkinsfile'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Step B"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you also need your jenkins to discover this new branch - this will depend on how you have configured the job. The above assumes that you have a multibranch pipeline job which is configured to include that branch.

Comment: Yeah this definitely works but I want a solution for incrementally updating the Jenkinsfile. For ex - I want to add a new step on the pipeline but before merging the new Jenkinsfile to the master I want to test it if the new stage{} is working fine. Currently, Jenkinsfile is being picked up from the master branch and I'm not able to test my change because that stage{} is not available in the master.

Comment: You need to define the job to discover pipelines on other branches,a s I mentioned in the answer. A common approach is to discover pull requests and use a `{ when {branch 'PR-*}}` condition.

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)